# Populate those customers with no transactions at day level with zero(0) (Teradata SQL Assistant)

Tags: sql, teradata

Probably somebody has created this before, but I need to create a dummy table to be able to union to my other transaction table.
The use case is,  I have daily transactional data with Fields like

```
  "customer", "date", "sales"
```

No I want a dummy data with the same fields populated by zero values at day level,
customer information should read from customer master but the date field should be pre-generated at day level at least for current year and previous 3 years.
The idea is I want to union this dummy table to my original transaction table to be able to produced no null transactions at day level, and those days with no sales should be populated by zero.
This requirement is for BI Analytics projects.
The make it simple I don't want my table to have a missing transactions at day level.

---

Here is the sample screenshot

[image]

Comment: please provide sample data, expect output and DDL or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sounds like a CROSS JOIN between customers and your calendar. There might be better ways to achieve your final goal, e.g. using EXPAND ON to create missing dates.

Comment: Different customers per day? How many rows will be processed by the BI tool in everage/max?